# Grafana Contact Point: How to access the data contained in .ValueString in a programmatic way?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, grafana-templating, grafana-alerts

**The setup**

For a Contact Point configured to use Slack
"Text Body" field contains the following:

```
{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}
  Type: {{ .CommonLabels.type }}

  {{ range .Alerts }}
    Status: {{ .Status }}

    {{ range .Labels.SortedPairs }}
      {{ .Name }}:   {{ .Value }}
    {{ end }}

    {{ .ValueString }}

    DashboardURL: {{ .DashboardURL }}
  {{ end }}
{{ else }}
  Stabilized
  threshhold: {{ .CommonLabels.threshold }}
  type: {{ .CommonLabels.type }}
{{ end }}
```

The above works as expected and looks great, with only one exception. In what is output by {{ .ValueString }} I see a lot of valuable data I'd like to access in a more granular/programmatic way. Right now one example of this output is a String that looks like:

```
"[ metric='twinkie_product_collection Rate' labels={job=twinkie_product_collection, types=runRate} value=1.1111111111111112 ],
[ metric='concert_ticket_collection Rate' labels={job=concert_ticket_collection, types=runRate} value=1.1111111111111112 ]"
```

The problem is this is an ugly string, I'd like to extract data like the metric, types and value to display in a more formatted way. Similarly to how I'm able to display `.Labels` data with:

```
{{ range .Labels.SortedPairs }}
  {{ .Name }}:   {{ .Value }}
{{ end }}
```

I've been referencing the documentation [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/contact-points/message-templating/template-data/) and the only two `KeyValue` types I see on an Alert besides `.Labels` is `.Annotations`, but when I try to display this annotation data in the same way there is nothing in there. So my main question is:

**How can I access and display the data contained in `.ValueString` in a programmatic way?**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `valueString`, you can access values in the Alert description programmatically:

Raw value string:

```
[ var='B0' metric='Value' labels={job_name=some-job-123} value=1202 ], 
[ var='B1' metric='Value' labels={job_name=another-job-234} value=601 ]
```

In the Alert description:

```
{{ range $k, $v := $values }}
{{ $k }}={{ $v }}
The value is {{ $v }} and the labels are {{ $v.Labels }}
{{ $v.Labels.job_name }}
{{ index $v.Labels "job_name"}}
{{ end }}
```

Alert output:

```
B0=1202
The value is 1202 and the labels are map[job_name:some-job-123]
some-job-123
some-job-123

B1=601
The value is 601 and the labels are map[job_name:another-job-234]
another-job-234
another-job-234
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It is a string, so you will need to parse it first, which will be complicated on the Golang template level.

I would recommend to use query, which will group by all required labels + use expression for alert condition. Then customize summary/description, where you can access that "ValueString" in structured way. See example: https://youtu.be/UtmmhLraSnE?t=964 I would say that is Grafana native approach.